# What is wrong with this attempt using php to include functions.php and header.php file?

Tags: php

What, if anything, is wrong with this code? I'm a beginner.  I'm trying to include a header file but when I test and try to load it says it's not working.

```
<?php include("http://test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/includes/header.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP doesn't say `it's not working`. What's the real error message?

Comment: www.test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/staff.php will give you the error message

Comment: <?php require_once("http://test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php include("http://test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/includes/header.php"); ?>

Comment: @Michael , we recieve internal server error 500; Probably you have the actual error?

Comment: That gives a `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`. You'll have to look into your `error.log` to find out the reason.

Comment: you probably shouldn't be including `http://` files this way in the first place, but specify a file path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell for your `HTTP 500` error. But you are clearly using `include()` wrong.

The `include` or `require_once` statement is used to load local php files. You should not have a reason to include URLs. Rewrite it to:

```
<?php
   require_once("./includes/functions.php");
   include("./includes/header.php");
?>
```

Adapt the path.

Comment: Including php files via http(s) is considerd a security risk. (and is blocked by default)

Answer (score 0):

i tried to open this file but it appears that it's not exist

Comment: This is the whole file that I'm trying to load but i'm getting a server error

Comment: <?php require_once("http://test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php include("http://test.orwallo.com/widget_corp/includes/header.php"); ?>